# React createContext(null) not allowed with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to set up a React store using useReducer and useContext hooks. The React.createContext(defaultValue) is creating issues with my TS checker. I have tried a few different things, but essentially, I `createContext(null)` then in the component `useReducer()` to set state and dispatch, but when I call the Provider and pass the value as {state, dispatch}, it doesn't tells me "Type '{ state: any; dispatch: React.Dispatch; }' is not assignable to type 'null'.

I don't understand this because by the time it errors, I have assigned state and dispatch and the value should no longer be null.

Here is the Context Provider wrapper that I am trying to create.

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer, FC, Dispatch } from 'react';
import storeReducer, { initialState } from './reducer';
import { Action, State } from './types';
import { isNull } from 'util';

const StoreContext = createContext(null);

const StoreProvider:FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(storeReducer, initialState);
  const value = {state, dispatch}
  return (
    <StoreContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </StoreContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { StoreProvider, StoreContext };

export interface IStoreContext {
  dispatch: (action: Action<any>) => {};
  state: State;
}
```

if I leave it as simply `const StoreContext = createContext();`, then it complains that defaultValue is not being defined.

The crazy thing is I have lifted this from an old project and had no issues compiling.

Answer (score 34):

This may be a case where it is okay to temporarily cast it in order to save yourself a hassle:

```
interface Store {
  state: MyStateType,
  dispatch: Dispatch,
}

const StoreContext = createContext<Store>({} as Store);

const StoreProvider = ({children}) => {
  const {state, dispatch} = theseAreAlwaysPresent()

  return (
    <StoreContext.Provider value={{state, dispatch}}>
      {children}
    </StoreContext.Provider>
  )
}
...
```

Comment: Nice elegant solution.

Answer (score 11):

Since I just made an account to answer this, I can't comment above.
Alex Wayne is correct, that is acceptable to Typescript. However, the `useContext` hook won't really work for this because as far as Typescript is concerned, you may have a `null` value in that Context.

From original answer... here is our Context in Typescript
`const StoreContext = createContext<{state: MyStateType, dispatch: Dispatch} | null>(null);`

So, we need to create a new hook, let's call it `useContextAndErrorIfNull`. This would look like:

```
const useContextAndErrorIfNull = <ItemType>(context: Context<ItemType | null>): ItemType => {
  const contextValue = useContext(context);
  if (contextValue === null) {
    throw Error("Context has not been Provided!");
  }
  return contextValue;
}
```

Use this hook instead of `useContext` and it should all work well.

Comment: Perfect, this works great when you know you'll never use your context when the provider hasn't been initialised

Comment: Thanks for taking time to create account just to answer this one

Answer (score 10):

When you initialize a context with `null`, the intended type can't be inferred. You have to give the type of the context explicitly in this case.

Here that would look something like:

```
const StoreContext = createContext<{
  state: MyStateType,
  dispatch: Dispact,
} | null>(null);
```

Comment: I have tried that. When I declare the type I get it working but then in the consumer (where I call useContext), I get the following error: `Argument of type 'Context<MyContextType | null>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Context<MyContextType>'.`
I created an interface for "MyContextType" that looks like this: 
`export interface MyContextType {
  state: State;
  dispatch: Dispatch<any>;
}`. And here is the context callback in the consumer:
`const ctx = useContext<MyContextType>(StoreContext)`

Comment: It doesn't like a `null` as a value when I initialize, but it doesn't let me declare `<TypeName | null>` either.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //So basically in my case you just have to assign an empty object that 
   will solve your problem.


 import React, { createContext, useReducer, FC, Dispatch } from 'react';
 import storeReducer, { initialState } from './reducer';
 import { Action, State } from './types';
 import { isNull } from 'util';

 // replaced null with {}
 // because assigning a value and any type of parameter will not be 
    acceptable in typescript
 const StoreContext = createContext({});

const StoreProvider:FC = ({ children }) => {
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(storeReducer, initialState);
const value = {state, dispatch}
return (
<StoreContext.Provider value={value}>
  {children}
</StoreContext.Provider>
 )};

export { StoreProvider, StoreContext };

export interface IStoreContext {
dispatch: (action: Action<any>) => {};
state: State;
}
```